# Is there a possibility to get a private member and use it's information/functions?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr, getter

I have been getting a really puzzling SEGFAULT in my code at runtime. Here is the breakdown of the situation:

```
///The following is only an example of the situation
class SimpleChar{
    private:
    int level;
    float health;
    std::shared_ptr<Item> inventory[20];
    public:
    std::shared_ptr<Item> getInventory(int i){return inventory[i];};
};

class Item{
    private:
    int itemID,Str,Dex,Int;
    Coord3 pos;
    public:
    int getItemID(){return itemID;};
    int getStr(){return Str;};
    Coord3 getPos(){return pos;};
};

struct Coord3{
    float x,y,z;
    void setPos(float tx,float ty,float tz){
        x=tx;y=ty;z=tz;}
};

int main(){
    //myChar is a member variable of another class, placed in main to simulate the pointer
    SimpleChar *myChar= some_other_instance.getTarget();
    ///other initialize code for myChar

    ///In this if statement, which lines would not work?
    if(myChar->getInventory(0).get()!=NULL){
        myChar->getInventory(0)->getPos().setPos(0,0,0);
        std::cout<<myChar->getInventory(0)->getStr()<<std::endl;
            myChar->getInventory(0)->doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

The code above gives an idea of what line the SEGFAULT fell on. The SEGFAULT is real:

```
//SEGFAULT, actual copied segfault from the line: if(myChar->getInventory(0).get()!=NULL)
#0 00993891 std::tr1::__shared_ptr<Carp::Item, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)1>::get(this=0x4d0) (z:/cpp programming/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/tr1/shared_ptr.h:685)
#1 00413D09 Carp::WinBag::update(this=0x2857f8, o=false) (Z:\CPP Programming\Carperon\Source\Carp\Interface.cpp:53)
#2 00416B5C Carp::GameUI::checkUpdate(this=0x2857e4) (Z:\CPP Programming\Carperon\Source\Carp\Interface.cpp:231)
#3 00401B7B Carp::GameApp::loopGame(this=0x27cca8) (Z:\CPP Programming\Carperon\main.cpp:35)
#4 00401EBB _fu2039___ZSt4cout() (Z:\CPP Programming\Carperon\Source\Application.cpp:17)
#5 004017A9 main() (Z:\CPP Programming\Carperon\main.cpp:6)
```

When seeing this I fail to understand what could be causing this problem. Would it be that I am using a getter function to use information of the member thats otherwise private? Or is there something else that is wrong with how I am "getting" the object?

What could I do to properly get `myChar`'s information without causing a SEGFAULT, and use it's information/functions accordingly?

Comment: Have you actually *allocated* the `Item` objects you store in the shared pointers?

Comment: Also, have you checked what you're doing on line 53 in the Interface.cpp file? Or line 231 in the same file? Or line 35 in the main.cpp file? The backtrace is *not* from the program you show us, so it's hard (if not impossible) to guess what's wrong. Can you please put together a *proper* [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: when you say _allocated_, do you mean there is something else that needs to be done to use the shared pointers? I don't recall ever having to do anything else after declaring the shared pointer in previous versions of my program. Would it need to be something done in the constructor? Because I recently added default constructors to my classes. I can provide the Item constructor with its `inventory` if needed

Comment: Alright, I'm going to load up a pastebin file of the exact code. I will link it in a few minutes (as well as remove the junk code)

Comment: Yes, an uninitialized shared pointer is just like any other uninitialized pointer. You actually have to allocate the pointer it should contain, like e.g. `std::shared_ptr<Item> mySharePtr(new Item);`

Comment: Ah, I see. So calling the shared_ptr is not enough. That should fix this problem if I just add that into the constructor. `mySharePtr.reset();` should be good enough for that right?

Comment: I'm going to attempt the reset() and I'll be back with the results.

Comment: Yes, calling `reset` to set the pointer should be enough. At least if you set it to a valid pointer. :)

Comment: As of now I am resetting to a blank, `mySharePtr.reset();` should work since it would at least give it the `NULL` pointer that my if statement is looking for. The above code will not execute if the pointer is `NULL`, its a nice way to know if something is there or not :)

Comment: With the code you provide we can't reproduce the error. There are bits missing, e.g. how the values in your objects get initialized. I tried to make it compile and with the least possible changes, yet there seems to be nothing wrong: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f4506a02736e4eb. Feel free to edit the code to reflect what is really going wrong in your case. In short: please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Alright. When looking at my code as carefully as possible, I noticed something extremely dangerous (in an array case). There was an if-else statement that was, when it didnt find an item in the shared_ptr, swapping that blank item with an item that doesnt exist. Example: `item[0].swapWith(item[-1]);`. This single mislook has caused all of this trouble for me today...I think I'm done for the night... Apologies for all the trouble..

Comment: @Molma that's what the mere production of an SSCCE can be good for - looking closely at the code again, narrowing down the problem and normally finding it yourself. Everytime I tried it, I came across the mistake I made, except once when it was a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems related to the very first line.

Are you sure that `myChar` is not `NULL` to begin with? What is `getTarget`? Can it return a null pointer?

Answer (score 0):

If you would try to use private member information the compiler say you that and the program doesn't  compile.

Your description of `main` function here is unclear. But it looks like you use `some_other_instance` before initialising it properly, so most probably `myChar` is null. Just add a check in your program or check it with `cout`.